# why does dvisvgm fail on this tikz figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvisvgm

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\draw[help lines] grid (5, 5);
\draw[fill=magenta!10] (1, 1) rectangle (2, 2);
\draw[fill=magenta!10] (2, 1) rectangle (3, 2);
\draw[fill=magenta!10] (3, 1) rectangle (4, 2);
\draw[fill=magenta!10] (3, 2) rectangle (4, 3);
\draw[fill=magenta!10] (2, 3) rectangle (3, 4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I ran

```
latexmk -xelatex -etex sample.tex
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --exact sample.xdv sample.svg
```

and got an empty output.
Using pdf2svg instead succeeds.

Why does my dvisvg command fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, TikZ creates PDF specials when used together with `xelatex -no-pdf`. dvisvgm doesn't support these specials and therefore the generated SVG contains no graphics.
In order to create proper specials, either process the `.tex` file with `latex` instead of `xelatex`, or add document class option `dvisvgm`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvisvgm]{standalone}
```